# Let G be a group such that |G|= 2n. Let R be the equivalence relation de

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let G be a group such that |G|= 2n. Let R be the equivalence relation
defined by xRy if x=y or x=y^-1.

Show that there are at least two equivalence classes of the form {x}.

Deduce that G has an element of order 2.

To be honest, I don't quite understand the first part of the question. Should I find a subgroup of G with Lagrange Theorem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An equivalence relation has been defined on $G$. Using that, let $g \in G$ be such that $g \neq e$. Ask yourself: what is the equivalence class  $[g]$ of $g$ under this relation. Observe that the only elements related to $g$ are $g$ itself or $g^{-1}$. So,
$$[g]=\{g,g^{-1}\}.$$
What if $g=e$? Then 
$$[e]=\{e\}.$$
**Ask yourself: is $e$ the only element whose equivalence class is of size $1$?**

If for all $g \in G-\{e\}$, the size of $[g]$ was $2$, then we would have an odd number of elements in $G$ (because $[e]$ has only $1$ element). But that contradicts the fact that $|G|$ is even. So there must be some $g \in G-\{e\}$ such that size of $[g]$ is $1$. This would mean $g=g^{-1}$, said differently $g^2=e$ or $|g|=2$.

Comment: Thanks so much! However, can you explain a little bit more why "we would have an odd number of elements in G"？Is there a relationship between the equivalence class size and the number of elements?

Comment: @davidD A set is partitioned by an equivalence relation into (disjoint) equivalence classes. So if we take the **disjoint** union of all the equivalence classes we get the set. In the finite case, it also means that the sum of the sizes of disjoint equivalence classes will be the size of the set. In this case $G$ is that set. So $|G|=\sum_{g \in G}[g]$ (disjoint sum). Since $|[e]|=1$, so if all other classes had size $2$, then the sum would be an odd number.

Comment: I see! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Since $|G|$ is even and the identity $e$ is in relation with itself, there must be at least another element $x \in G$. If $x$ is idempotent, i.e. $x\ast x = e$, then we are done.
Otherwise we just notice that at most there can be $n-1$ classes of objects $\{x\}$ with $x \neq e$, thence there must be an idempotent element $y$.